# Angular2 disable submit button if form is invalid

Tags: forms, angular, submit

How can I make submit button disabled, when my form is invalid in Angular2?

Now I use code:

```
<input type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid" value="Zarejestruj">
```

and this is not working and make form always disabled, also when this is valid.

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:

I found error, in form I have file input and this causes form button failed. Here is my whole code (without validation tips)

```
<div class="form">
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Nazwa użytkownika" [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['login']">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Hasło" [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['password']" validateEqual="repeatPassword" reverse="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło" [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['repeatPassword']" validateEqual="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="file" name="avatar" file-model="avatar" [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['avatar']" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-row submit">
            <input type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid" value="Zarejestruj">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And registration.component.ts:

```
/ Imports
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app/registration/registration.component.html'
})
// Component class implementing OnInit
export class RegistrationComponent {

registrationForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
    this.registrationForm = fb.group({
      'login' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(12)])],
      'password' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'repeatPassword':  [null, Validators.required],
      'avatar': [null, Validators.required],
    })
  }

  RegisterUser(value: any){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Now the question is: why this does not working?

Comment: please post the code for the whole form: this is not information to see your problem sorry! Are you using reactive or template forms?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Your question now indicates you found an error? If you have solved it you can [post an answer to your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: Definitely stil. I don't understand why input file does not working properly. And what I need changed with this code?